# How to change load-balancing algorithm in Gateway

Tags: java, spring-boot, load-balancing, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-gateway

I am developing an microservices based app in Spring Boot 3.1.2. I need to change the default algorithm built into the gateway load balancer (load balancing on the server side is mandatory), specifically I need to integrate Weighted Response Time algorithm, I know that this algorithm already exists in Spring Cloud.

The app has three microservices:

- Eureka
- Gateway
- Microservice random

Eureka and Gateway class are by default, microservice random has only one route that returns the port. The configuration is:

**Eureka (application.properties)**

```
server.port=8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
spring.application.name=eureka-server
```

**Gateway (application.properties)**

```
server.port=8080
spring.main.web-application-type=reactive

eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:8761/eureka/

spring.cloud.loadbalancer.ribbon.enabled=false
spring.cloud.loadbalancer.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true

spring.cloud.gateway.httpclient.wiretap=true

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=mrrandom
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://MRRANDOM
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/**
```

Should I change the configuration (application.properties) or create a configuration class?

I have searched for official documentation but I have not found it, everything there is for ribbon, but ribbon is deprecated, all the internet examples use client side load balancing, but I need server side load balancing.

Comment: Have you tried setting `spring.cloud.loadbalancer.configurations` to `weighted` (please see the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#weighted-load-balancing)? Is `MRRANDOM` your service id? SC LoadBalancer is a client-side solution, what do you mean by "server-side loadbalancing" in your use-case.

Comment: @OlgaMaciaszek Thank you very much. Yes, I have tried ```spring.cloud.loadbalancer.configurations=weighted``` in application.properties of Gateway but it didn't work. Yes, MRRANDOM is the service id. I have no problem deploying 2 instances of MRRANDOM, however, I cannot modify the round robin algorithm. I know that SC LoadBalancer is a client-side solution, but I want ribbon alternative because I need to integrate load balancing in Eureka or Gateway and not in MRRANDOM

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly. Can you provide a sample?